# JSP Redirect submit value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a jsp like this and  i want to process the some input data. why did the current jsp dont wait for submit the value and then execute the servlet? The site redirect immediately to the defined next page. I want to show the page and the user should put into a value and then redirect.

Here my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/resources/taglibs.jsp"%>

<%
session.setAttribute("MyName", System.getProperty("user.name"));
request.setAttribute("hideNav", true);
%>

<fmt:setLocale value="${lang}" />
<fmt:bundle basename="messages">
<t:template>
    <jsp:attribute name="header"> 
        <fmt:message key="topic.bag_transfer" />
    </jsp:attribute>

    <jsp:attribute name="navigation_static">
        <li><a href="info"><font size="+0.1">${lang}</font></a></li>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <p class="msg">
            <fmt:message key="all.message" />
            <c:out value="${requestScope.Message}" />
        </p>
        <%--Form--%>
        <form method="post" action="login">
            <div>
                <p class="f_head">
                    <fmt:message key="all.user" />
                </p>
                <p class="f_form">
                    <input id="1" class="f_txt" type="text" name="login"    />
                </p>
                <%--button--%>
                <p class="f_form_bl">
                    <input id="3" class="f_btn" type="submit" name="btn"   value="Weiter" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>     
    </jsp:body>
</t:template>
```

and a servlet like this

```
public class BagScanStartLocation extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final String PAGE_JSP_THIS = "/bag_scan_start_location.jsp"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final String PAGE_JSP_LOGIN = "/"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final String PAGE_JSP_NEXT = "/scan_bag.jsp"; //$NON-NLS-1$

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    Locale lang = (Locale) session.getAttribute("lang"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    AppsSession myAppsUser = (AppsSession) session.getAttribute("USER"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    //.....

    request.setAttribute("UserName", myAppsUser.getUserName()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    request.setAttribute("messageText", "Test"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    RequestDispatcher disp =     this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/scan_bag.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
}
```

I tried it with a simple example:

servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
// reading the user input
 String color= request.getParameter("color");    
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println (

  "<html> \n" +
    "<head> \n" +
      "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;   charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
      "<title> My first jsp  </title> \n" +
    "</head> \n" +
    "<body> \n" +
      "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" +
        "Hello World" +
      "</font> \n" +
    "</body> \n" +
  "</html>" 
);
```

jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> My first JSP   </title>
</head> 
<body>      
    <form action="BagScanStartLocation">            
         Please enter a color <br>
        <input type="text" name="color"size="20px">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">                        
    </form>     
</body>
```

i linked it in topic.jsp like this

```
                <li><a id="10" href="bag_scan_start_location"> <fmt:message key="topic.bag_transfer" /></a></li>
```

and web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BagScanStartLocation</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bag_scan_start_location</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>BagScanStartLocation</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BagScanStartLocation</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.blablabla.oracle.blab.BagScanStartLocation</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

when i click on the topic href the servlet will execute immediately. Why is the JSP **not shown**?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>bla_WA</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Root</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.bla.Root</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Info</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.InfoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testreplier</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.testreplier</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.CycleCountIndex</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountLocator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.CycleCountLocator</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountAddItem</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.CycleCountAddItem</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.SimpleCycleCountIndex</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountLocator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.SimpleCycleCountLocator</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountAddItem</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.SimpleCycleCountAddItem</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReturnMtxIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.ReturnMtxIndex</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PAGE_JSP_THIS</param-name>
        <param-value>/return_mtx_index.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReturnMtxIndexPocket</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.ReturnMtxIndex</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PAGE_JSP_THIS</param-name>
        <param-value>/return_mtx_index_pocket.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvMtxIndex</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxOverview</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvMtxOverview</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxItem</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvMtxItem</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxBook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvMtxBook</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxClose</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvMtxClose</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvJitIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvJitIndex</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PalletPick</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.PalletPick</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RcvBBIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.RcvBBIndex</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ZPixCall</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.util.ZPixCall</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>XtimeLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.XtimeLogin</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PAGE_JSP_THIS</param-name>
        <param-value>/xtime_login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DoSo</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DoSo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DoSo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DlcClearingPoint</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DlcClearingPoint</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DlcClearingPoint</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DlcKidToLoc</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DlcKidToLoc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DlcKidToLoc</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DlcKeToKid</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DlcKeToKid</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DlcKeToKid</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DlcInvoice</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DlcInvoice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DlcInvoice</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DlcStatusMonitor</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DlcStatusMonitor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.DlcStatusMonitor</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>BagScanStartLocation</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BagScanStartLocation</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.BagScanStartLocation</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>ScanBag</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ScanBag</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.xxx.oracle.xxsh.ScanBag</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Root</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Info</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/info</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testreplier</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testreplier</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cycle_count_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountLocator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cycle_count_locator</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CycleCountAddItem</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cycle_count_add_item</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/simple_cycle_count_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountLocator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/simple_cycle_count_locator</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCycleCountAddItem</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/simple_cycle_count_add_item</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReturnMtxIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/return_mtx_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReturnMtxIndexPocket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/return_mtx_index_pocket</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_mtx_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxOverview</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_mtx_overview</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxItem</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_mtx_item</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxBook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_mtx_book</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvMtxClose</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_mtx_close</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvJitIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_jit_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PalletPick</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pallet_pick</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XtimeLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xtime_login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RcvBBIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rcv_bb_index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ZPixCall</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zpixcall</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DoSo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DoSo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DlcClearingPoint</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dlc_clearing_point</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DlcKidToLoc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dlc_kid_to_loc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DlcKeToKid</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dlc_ke_to_kid</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DlcInvoice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dlc_invoice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DlcStatusMonitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dlc_statusmonitor</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BagScanStartLocation</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bag_scan_start_location</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ScanBag</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/scan_bag</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
    <description>description</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ORACLE_APPS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-    1">
    <title> My first JSP   </title>
</head> 
<body>      
    <form action="BagScanStartLocation" method="get">           
         Please enter a color <br>
        <input type="text" name="color"size="20px">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">                        
    </form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a wrong configuration in the web.xml. i build the project up from the scratch and it works.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your doGet() you invoke doPost() method;

Comment: A little hard to get connections between this pieces of code? but let's try: 
When you click on your href link, it send GET request to BagScanStartLocation servlet, right? 
Then it invoke doGet, then doPost and forward you to piece of jsp with form for color input? 
And it immediately redirect you into next servlet? Probably it happens because forward from doPost method. 

Try replace all from doPost to doGet in BagScanStartLocation servlet

Comment: If not please show full jsp which make redirect and full web.xml

Comment: The JSP is not shown. I would expect first the page to enter the color and then the result from the servlet.

Comment: Ok. You click href="bag_scan_start_location". And after that you want jsp with form for color input, but it not shown? url 'bag_scan_start_location' lead us into servlet BagScanStartLocation#doGet. and here you have not invoke doPost, but forward to your "jsp_with_form.jsp"(i don't see the name of it in code)

Comment: You click href="bag_scan_start_location". And after that you want jsp with form for color input, but it not shown? --exactly

Comment: So definitely you show rewrite your BagScanStartLocation#doGet method to getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(formPage.jsp).forward(request, response); where 'formPage.jsp' - youe jsp file name with form; probably it has name "/bag_scan_start_location.jsp"?